# Calculate only value of vat

Tags: php

I trying to calculate but can't get this done, if someone can help

I have the total of the order and the vat at 23%

```
 $vat = 23;

 $total = 6.00;
```

For add the vat to total I will do

```
 $total_with_vat = $total * $vat;
```

that will be 7.40

I now the total is 6.00, but how can I get the 1.40 of the vat

I need this to make some calculations. Looks simple but I'am not getting only to do it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a basic math problem, not programming: `$total_vat = $total * $vat / 100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple

```
$vat = $total * $vat / 100.0;
// 1.38
```

If you'd like to guarantee 2 digits of precision, you can use `round`

```
$vat = round($vat, 2);
```

---

Make it into a reusable function

```
function calculateVat($amount, $vat=23) {
  return round($amount * $vat / 100.0, 2);
}

$amount = 6.00;
$vat    = calculateVat($amount);
// 1.38
```

If VAT is a different amount, you can specify it as a second argument

```
$amount = 6.00;
$vat    = calculateVat($amount, 30);
// 1.8
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I not explaning well I just want the value of the vat, I want only the 1.40

Comment: Thanks for that just what I wanted